# Is this a proper XML syntax

Tags: xml, vbscript

I was wondering if this was a proper XML syntax, because I need to remove a node in this document using VBscript and I really am not able to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dbm>
  <servers>
    <server name="PCTEST">
      <references>
        <database name="TES1" path="\C$\Build"/>
      </references>
    </server>
  </servers>
</dbm>
```

Comment: Looks like it's fine - what problem are you having?

Comment: Well I can't figure out how to delete the database node from the file and then save it with vbscript, I've been trying for ages.  SO i thought maybe the node itself was not legal or  something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmldoc.async = false
xmldoc.loadXml _
  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
  "<dbm>" & _
  "  <servers>" & _
  "    <server name='PCTEST'>" & _
  "      <references>" & _
  "        <database name='TES1' path='\C$\Build'/>" & _
  "      </references>" & _
  "    </server>" & _
  "  </servers>" & _
  "</dbm>"

''// Removing a single node
Set nodeToBeRemoved = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//database[@name='TES1']")
If Not nodeToBeRemoved Is Nothing Then
   nodeToBeRemoved.parentNode.RemoveChild nodeToBeRemoved
End if

''// Removing multiple nodes
Set nodesToBeRemoved = xmldoc.selectNodes("//database")
For Each nodeToBeRemoved In nodesToBeRemoved
    nodeToBeRemoved.parentNode.RemoveChild nodeToBeRemoved
Next

''// alert xmldoc.xml
```

Comment: Thank you worked, but I'm not sure to understand the syntax you used to select the node ("//database[@name='TES1']").  If I wanted to select all database nodes if I had several would I do SelectNodes("//database") only? Thanks for your answer

Comment: You're right, `SelectNodes` will do the trick; I updated my answer to reflect that example. About sintax, that's a `XPath` expression: http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/

Answer (score 1):

It ***might*** be.

Without a schema (like an [xsd](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/default.asp) or a [dtd](http://xmlfiles.com/dtd/)) it is impossible to know for sure.

Some parsers/manipulators validate against a schema, and sometimes they are configured to use an *external* schema, which means your program may (earlier than you think) load some schemas and fail your requests to remove or manipulate the document in a way that the schema doesn't permit.

If you're not using a schema, or (worse) you're using an ad-hoc parser that you, or someone at your company wrote) then I'd suspect there's a bug in your parser.

Answer (score 0):

Although i could not find XML document from the list, Direct Input with detecting automatically validates XML easily.

Edit: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine but if you want a handy (free) tool for validating & working with XML, [Microsoft's XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en) is pretty useful.

One thing you might want to check for is that your file's encoding matches UTF-8: http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_encoding.asp .